# How to make a filter query across all tenants ignoring the namespace of each tenant (i.e. a query with WILDCARD namespace ) in objectify

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a multitenant application in which each school is a tenant. Each school can have many teachers. So I have two kind of entity one is "School" and second is "Teacher" such that each teacher has a parent school. I am using @Parent annotation of objectify for building the relationship between school and teacher.

Now I want to count the number of teachers across the schools for my admin portal.Is there any concept of global namespace in objectify/datastore?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix namespaces or go across all namespaces in a single query. As far as I know, you have no option, but to run multiple queries for each namespace.

A workaround could be - to maintain an "admin" namespace and keep track of teacher counts for each school and/or count for all schools. This means, when you insert/delete a teacher entity in any namespace, you would update the count in the "admin" namespace.

Comment: I am already doing like you are saying i.e. running queries on each namespace. But i don't want that because there are more than 100 schools(tenants) and it may grow as well so getting all the namespaces first by one query then making queries on teachers in given namespace, i don't think is a good way. for 100 tenants in worst case i required to make  1+100 queries if I am not wrong.So there should be a better way to do that something like a Wildcard namespace

Comment: I think that defeats the purpose of multi-tenancy and increases the risk of data leaks. Imagine what would happen if you accidentally start showing one tenant's data to the other. Again, if all you need is some basic statistics such as teacher count, you should consider the workaround I suggested.

Comment: There are many other things that admin portal need to show which required these kind of queries . count is an example.